# How do I remove the main product image?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, product, image

I want to programmatically remove ALL product images as I am going to programmatically re-add all images. I've managed to remove gallery images (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709496/magento-programmatically-remove-product-images) but I can't get rid of that main image.

I can delete it from the file system obviously but that still leaves a placeholder (with broken image).

Any tips on how to remove the image without removing the product would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying out a bunch of different versions I landed in this one which works for me every time. The key for me was removing all image settings for each store before I could completely delete the images from the system.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');


// Retrieve all products. You could populate the array from, for example, a list of SKUS if you only want to delete images on a subset
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$prodIds=$products->getCollection()->getAllIds();
$nrOfProducts = count($prodIds);

$values = array(
    'image'=>'no_selection',
    'small_image'=>'no_selection',
    'thumbnail'=>'no_selection',
);

//Populate this array with IDs of ALL your store fronts
$store_fronts = array(1,2);

foreach ($store_fronts as $store_front)
{
    Mage::app()->getStore()->setId($store_front);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($prodIds, $values, $store_front);
}
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($prodIds, $values, Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$counter = 0;
foreach($prodIds as $productId) {

    ++$counter;

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product = $products->load($productId);

    $attrCode         = 'media_gallery';
    $mediaGalleryData = $product->getData($attrCode);
    if (isset($mediaGalleryData['images'])) {
        foreach ($mediaGalleryData['images'] as &$image) {
            $image['removed'] = 1;
        }
        $product->setData($attrCode, $mediaGalleryData);
        echo "Saving product ".$name." (".$counter." / ".$nrOfProducts.") \n";
        try{
        $product->save();
        } catch (Exception $e)
        {
           echo "Exception saving ".$name.", skipping\n".$e->getMessage()."\n";
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    $attrCode         = 'media_gallery';
    $mediaGalleryData = $product->getData($attrCode);
    if (isset($mediaGalleryData['images'])) {
        foreach ($mediaGalleryData['images'] as &$image) {
            $image['removed'] = 1;
        }
        $product->setData($attrCode, $mediaGalleryData);
        $product->save();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the very fast answer mageUz. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to solve the problem, at least not for me. The main image is still not removed. In one example I had three images (one main and two in the gallery). The two images in the gallery are removed but not the main image. I can see that your code enters the for loop three times but somehow the "removed" is ignored for the main image.

Comment: Together with another response I used your code for a working solution. See my own answer to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should first reset all the image selections to 'no_selection' then try to remove the images.
This should do it:

```
//values for image attributes
//add others if you have
$values = array(
    'image'=>'no_selection',
    'small_image'=>'no_selection',
    'thumbnail'=>'no_selection',
);
//get all product ids
$productIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
//set new values.
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes($productIds, $values, 0);
```

After running this, you can try the solution from the link you mentioned.

Comment: Also realised it wouldn't delete the image unless it was removed from all store fronts. So I now run it on all store fronts first and finally the admin. Problem is it throws an exception when trying to save a product on a non-admin store. `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1874-0-3-1' for key 'CC12C83765B562314470A24F2BDD0F36'' in /.../html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php:1348` Any ideas on that @Marius or anyone else?

Comment: Solved the duplicate entry issue by applying @Marius code for each store front before attempting the delete. See my complete solution in the separate answer I posted.